# how to change OC JSContext[@"makeNSColor"] to swift

Tags: swift, javascriptcore

'JSContext' has no subscript member,oc is ok ,but swift not work

I have tried with swift 4

OC is OK,for example

```
JSContext *context = [[JSContext alloc] init];
context[@"makeNSColor"] = ^(NSDictionary *rgb)
{float r = rgb[@"red"].floatValue;
float g = rgb[@"green"].floatValue;
float b = rgb[@"blue"].floatValue;
return [NSColor colorWithRed:(r / 255.f) green:(g / 255.f) blue:(b / 255.f) alpha:1.0];
};
```

Swift is Error:

```
var context = JSContext() as? JSContext     //Cannot assign value of type 'Any?' to type 'JSContext?'

        context!["makeNSColor"] = { rgb in     //Type 'JSContext' has no subscript member

            var r: Float = rgb?["red"].floatValue

            var g: Float = rgb?["green"].floatValue

            var b: Float = rgb?["blue"].floatValue

            return NSColor(red: CGFloat((r / 255.0)), green: CGFloat((g / 255.0)), blue: CGFloat((b / 255.0)), alpha: 1.0)

        }
```

it has two errors: Cannot assign value of type 'Any?' to type 'JSContext?', Type 'JSContext' has no subscript member,I don't know how to fix it ,can you tell me how to solve it ,thanks a lot.

I tried to change  context!   as!  NSMutableDictionary,or [String,Any],but still error,can't change

Comment: Did you read the documentation, did you search on-line for solutions? What about doing `let context = JSContext()!` and what about using `objectForKeyedSubscript` to get that value?

Comment: Did you ask https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/116063 in the Apple Forum? From the recommended link https://nshipster.com/javascriptcore/ given in an answer: *“Conversely, you can set Swift values as variables in a JSContext by calling the setObject(_:forKeyedSubscript:) method.”*

Comment: Show me definition or value `makeNSColor` in JS.

Answer (score 2):

Use following for swift equivalent

```
let colorHandle: @convention(block) ([String : Any]) -> UIColor = { rgb in
    let r = rgb["red"] as! CGFloat
    let g = rgb["green"] as! CGFloat
    let b = rgb["blue"] as! CGFloat

    return UIColor(red: r / 255.0, green: g / 255.0, blue: b / 255.0, alpha: 1.0)
}

context?.setObject(colorHandle, forKeyedSubscript: "makeNSColor" as NSCopying & NSObjectProtocol)
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what is an object `makeNSColor`. But if it is `var makeNSColor = {red : 10/255, green : 10/255, blue : 255/255, a : 1};`, here is a good example how to create UIColor from dictionary `makeNSColor`:

```
    func f () {
        let context = JSContext()!
        let script = """
var makeNSColor = {red : 10/255, green : 10/255, blue : 255/255, a : 1};
"""
        let cc = context.evaluateScript(script).context // result is
        let val = cc?.objectForKeyedSubscript("makeNSColor")
        guard let dict = val?.toDictionary() as? [String : CGFloat] else {return}
        let color = UIColor(displayP3Red: dict["red"] ?? 0, green: dict["green"] ?? 0, blue: dict["blue"] ?? 0, alpha: dict["a"] ?? 0)

        print(color)
    }
```

If you want to create `makeNSColor` as `Dictionary` in JS, use next function:

```
    func addColor (r : Float, g : Float, b : Float) {
        let context = JSContext()!
        let script = """
var makeNSColor = {red : \(r)/255, green : \(g)/255, blue : \(b)/255, a : 1};
"""
        let cc = context.evaluateScript(script).context // result is

        // next code only needed to check the `makeNSColor`
        let val = cc?.objectForKeyedSubscript("makeNSColor")
        guard let dict = val?.toDictionary() as? [String : CGFloat] else {return}
        let color = UIColor(displayP3Red: dict["red"] ?? 0, green: dict["green"] ?? 0, blue: dict["blue"] ?? 0, alpha: dict["a"] ?? 0)

        print(color)
    }
```